# How do I add Ninject Controller Factory to an ASP.NET MVC app with OWIN?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, ninject, owin

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web Api 2.2 project with Visual Studio 2012 Premium, .NET Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

I have created an empty `ASP.NET MVC 5` project. I have deleted `Global.asax` and create this `Startup.cs` class:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost;
using Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost;
using Owin;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;
using MyProject.Web.API.App_Start;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyProject.Web.API.Startup))]
namespace MyProject.Web.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            var webApiConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
            webApiConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Default",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

            webApiConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            webApiConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ProductionOrderActionApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/MyProductionOrders/{orderNumber}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "MyProductionOrders" });

            app.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel);
            app.UseNinjectWebApi(webApiConfiguration);
        }

        private static StandardKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            RegisterServices(kernel);

            return kernel;
        }

        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            var containerConfigurator = new NinjectConfigurator();
            containerConfigurator.Configure(kernel);
        }
    }
}
```

The project works fine with [ApiController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=En-uS&k=k(System.Web.Http.ApiController);k(ApiController);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) classes, but when I try to access to a [Controller](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=En-us&k=k(System.Web.Mvc.Controller);k(Controller);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) I get the following error: `No Parameterless constructor defined for this object.`.

This is one of my `Controller`:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IExceptionLogHelper m_ExceptionLoggerHelper;
    private readonly IGenericRepository<MyModel> _myRepo;

    public MyController(
        IExceptionLogHelper exceptionLoggerHelper,
        IGenericRepository<MyModel> myModelRepo)
    {
        _exceptionLoggerHelper = exceptionLoggerHelper;
        _myRepo = myModelRepo;
    }

    //
    // GET: /UploadChinaCodes/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And `NinjectConfigurator` class:

```
public class NinjectConfigurator
{
    public void Configure(IKernel container)
    {
        AddBindings(container);
    }

    private void AddBindings(IKernel container)
    {

        // Exception logger.
        container.Bind<IExceptionLogHelper>().To<ExceptionLogHelper>();

        // Repositories.
        container.Bind<IGenericRepository<MyModel>>().To<GenericRepository<MyModel>>();
    }
}
```

And these are the installed NuGet packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.es" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.es" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.es" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject" version="3.2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Extensions.ContextPreservation" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost" version="3.2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.WebApi" version="3.2.4.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost" version="3.2.4.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

By the way, I'm using `Owin`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to add a parameterless constructor?

Comment: @Alberto the OP does not want a parameterless constructor, only a parameterized constructor for injecting dependencies. It seems like Ninject is not being used as the MVC Controller factory.

Comment: Indeed I wrote add: the parameterless will be used by MVC internals or  whatever needs it while the actual constructor by Ninject or OWIN.

Comment: I have added a NinjectControllerFactory but now I have another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827566/the-icontrollerfactory-ninjectcontrollerfactory-did-not-return-a-controller-for. I don't know if I have to delete this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a custom `DefaultControllerFactory` for ninject:

```
using Ninject;
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyProject.Web.API.Factories
{
    public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        public IKernel Kernel { get; private set; }

        public NinjectControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
        {
            this.Kernel = kernel;
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            IController controller = null;

            if (controllerType != null)
                controller = (IController)Kernel.Get(controllerType);

            return controller; 
        }
    }
}
```

And register it on `Startup` class:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost;
using Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost;
using Owin;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using MyProject.Web.API.Factories;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyProject.Web.API.Startup))]
namespace MyProject.Web.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            var webApiConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();

            webApiConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            webApiConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ProductionOrderActionApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/ProductionOrders/{orderNumber}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "ProductionOrders" });

            app.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel);
            app.UseNinjectWebApi(webApiConfiguration);
        }

        private static StandardKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory(kernel));
            RegisterServices(kernel);

            return kernel;
        }

        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            var containerConfigurator = new NinjectConfigurator();
            containerConfigurator.Configure(kernel);
        }
    }
}
```

I have added this line `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory(kernel));` on `CreateKernel` method.